# VBScript cut off end of filename after space but keep extension

Tags: vbscript

I've been searching online. Is there a way to cut off the space and the rest of the filename but leave the extension with VBScript.

Say I have a filename like this:

```
filename this is a file.txt
```

Could VBScript cut off the space and everything afterwards but leave the extension like this:

```
filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do some surgery with the string [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ca8tfek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) available in vbscript.

```
dim s
dim s2
s = "filename this is a file.txt"
s2 = Left(s, Instr(s, " ")-1)  & Right(s, Len(s) - InstrRev(s, ".") + 1)
msgbox s2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve what you want:

- Using a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2%28v=vs.84%29):

  ```
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "^(\S*).*(\..*?)$"

  Set f = fso.GetFile("filename this is a file.txt")
  f.Name = re.Replace(f.Name, "$1$2")
  ```
- Using [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29):

  ```
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set f = fso.GetFile("filename this is a file.txt")
  f.Name = Split(fso.GetBaseName(f))(0) & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(f)
  ```
- Using string functions: see [answer provided by KekuSemau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18320369/1630171).

Answer (score 0):

Use a RegExp to cut the first 'word' and the extension from your input:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "^(\w+)(.*)(\..*)$"
>> For Each s In Array("filename this is a file.txt", "a.txt", "1a nix ...txt")
>>     WScript.Echo s, """" & r.Replace(s, "$1$3") & """"
>> Next
>>
filename this is a file.txt "filename.txt"
a.txt "a.txt"
1a nix ...txt "1a.txt"
```

If you insist on staying with String ops, use Mid() instead of Right():

```
>> s = "filename this is a file.txt"
>> a = Left(s, InStr(s, " ") - 1)
>> b = Mid(s, InStrRev(s, "."))
>> WScript.Echo a, b, a & b
>>
filename .txt filename.txt
```